# Bibliography sorted in order of use, and a publications section sorted by date

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using biblatex with biber already, so this should be possible.  What I'm trying to get is:

- A full bibliography (superscript number style, numbered in order of appearance, nice and easy)

  and
- A list of my publications etc.  These may or may not appear in the bibliography. I use a `refsection` environment for this.

The MWE below does this, but the list of publications should be in date order without affecting the sort order of the main bibliography.  How do I do specify a sort order just for a `refsection`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    sorting=none,
    firstinits=true,
    maxbibnames=100,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sortcites=true,
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    natbib
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{me_poster,
    title="a poster",
    author="Me",
    keywords="me",
    year=2013
}
@article{me_article,
    title="a journal article",
    author="Me",
    journal="journal of stuff",
    year="2012",
    keywords="me"
}
@article{AuthorA_article,
    title="An Article",
    journal ="journal of applied stuff",
    author="Author, A",
    year="1999"
}
@book{AuthorB_book,
    title="A book",
    author="Author, B",
    year="1666"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \section{Body}
        Some people said some stuff.\supercite{AuthorA_article, AuthorB_book}
    \section{My publications}
        \begin{refsection}%
            \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}%
            \nocite{*}%
            \printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,keyword=me,title={Publications and presentations},heading=bibintoc]%
        \end{refsection}%
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply load `biblatex` without the `sorting` option and use that option when issuing `\printbibliography` commands.

So, for the full bibliography, you will use

```
\printbibliography[sorting=none]
```

while for the list of publications

```
\printbibliography[sorting=ynt,omitnumbers=true,keyword=me,title={Publications and presentations},heading=bibintoc]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    firstinits=true,
    maxbibnames=100,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sortcites=true,
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    natbib
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{me_poster,
    title="a poster",
    author="Me",
    keywords="me",
    year=2013
}
@article{me_article,
    title="a journal article",
    author="Me",
    journal="journal of stuff",
    year="2012",
    keywords="me"
}
@article{AuthorA_article,
    title="An Article",
    journal ="journal of applied stuff",
    author="Author, A",
    year="1999"
}
@book{AuthorB_book,
    title="A book",
    author="Author, B",
    year="1666"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \section{Body}
        Some people said some stuff.\supercite{AuthorA_article, AuthorB_book}
    \section{My publications}
        \begin{refsection}%
            \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}%
            \nocite{*}%
            \printbibliography[sorting=ynt,omitnumbers=true,keyword=me,title={Publications and presentations},heading=bibintoc]%
        \end{refsection}%
    \printbibliography[sorting=none]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Running your code here, I get an error (undefined control sequence) on `\supercite`, only when `sorting=none` is removed from the preamble. If I leave `sorting=none` in the preamble I get numbers in both bibliographies: Can I check what versions you've got? I'm on biblatex 2.8a, biber 1.8.

Comment: @ChrisH Delete the `.bbl` file.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this definition of a new sorting scheme `ymdnt`, which sorts by year,month,day,name,title.  This implementation sorts ascending, but it is easy to make it descending if desired.  The benefit comes in the proper sorting of items that use the `month`/`day` fields, which the standard `nyt` scheme does not consider.

I have also reworked some of your fixes to streamline them:

- We cite everything, then track them as they are cited to put in the regular bibliography.
- A new `bibenvironment` is used to remove the label (this will localize the change to the `labelnumberwidth` field format a bit nicer).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    sorting=none,
    firstinits=true,
    maxbibnames=100,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sortcites=true,
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    natbib
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{me_poster,
    title="a poster",
    author="Me",
    keywords="me",
    year=2013
}
@article{me_article,
    title="a journal article",
    author="Me",
    journal="journal of stuff",
    year="2012",
    keywords="me"
}
@article{AuthorA_article,
    title="An Article",
    journal ="journal of applied stuff",
    author="Author, A",
    year="1999"
}
@book{AuthorB_book,
    title="A book",
    author="Author, B",
    year="1666"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*} % Cite everything; we'll track them explicitly

% Add cited entries to cited category
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

% New bib environment: same as standard but with no numbers
\defbibenvironment{myrefs}
  {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang
     \itemindent-\leftmargin
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
     \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% Sort by year in Self Publications
% Create new sort scheme that includes year and month
\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
        \sort{                                                                                                                                                
                \field{presort}
        }
        \sort[final]{
                \field{sortkey}
        }
        \sort[direction=ascending]{ % Change if descending desired
                \field{sortyear}
                \field{year}
        }
        \sort[direction=ascending]{
                \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
                \literal{00}
        }
        \sort[direction=ascending]{
                \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
                \literal{00}
        }
        \sort{
                \name{sortname}
                \name{author}
                \name{editor}
                \name{translator}
                \field{sorttitle}
                \field{title}
        }
        \sort{
                \field{sorttitle}
        }
        \sort{
                \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
                \literal{0000}
        }
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Body}
        Some people said some stuff.\supercite{AuthorA_article, AuthorB_book}
    \section{My publications}
            \printbibliography[omitnumbers=true,env=myrefs,keyword=me,title={Publications and presentations},heading=bibintoc,sorting=ymdnt]

    \printbibliography[category=cited]
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: bibliography]

Comment: I liked the simplicity of the other answer, but your new environment definitely improves that page.