# How could I recreate Cal Newport's LaTeX CV?

Tags: formatting, cv

How would I go about recreating Cal Newport's CV? It looks really slick, but I'm new to LaTeX and don't know how to get started.

http://people.cs.georgetown.edu/~cnewport/pubs/CalvinNewportCV.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't treat it as a particularly good example.  P2 has only 1 line; useful information is interspersed with the publications (etc.). For many purposes 12pp is too much - a more compact way of listing publications would be better.  It appears to be autogenerated so it would mostly be biblatex macros and clever use of keywords in a .bib file.  We have some questions on that, for example [one I asked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179777/28808) (not the best example, just a hook for your searching.  We're not really geared up to "do it for me" questions - try something and ask specifics

Comment: I think the way to get started would be to [read an introduction](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html).

Comment: it looks a pretty basic document, but the thing has an email address on it why not just ask for the source. rather than asking people to reverse engineer it from the pdf?

Comment: No need to go full LaTeX for a cv. I have one cv design that I am very proud of and it can be built in two minutes! Here: https://lf-araujo.github.io/Yet-Another-CV

Comment: What part is 'really slick'? It is probably easily implemented. (Note also that the metadata suggests he has used someone else's CV as a model (see the `Creator` line).

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy and automated way of getting what you want, but using pandoc instead of pure Latex. The output will end up looking even better than the design you mention.

[image: cv template]

You have to install a few things first:

- git (pacman -S git);
- Fira Mono & Minion Pro fonts (not easy, depending on your system);
- Awesome fonts;
- a working pandoc (pacman -S pandoc pandoc-citeproc pandoc-crossref) and a xelatex installation;
- and the installation of my repo (see below).

Install my repository by cloning it:

```
git clone https://github.com/lf-araujo/yapcvt
cd yapcvt
```

Now you will find a cv.md file inside the /source directory. It starts with a yaml code block (the part between the three dashes), where you can send the desired options to pandoc. You don't have to change those, as I let them as near as possible to [Butterick's Practical Typography](http://practicaltypography.com/) recommendations.

Note that the items are laid out in a list of descriptions, with the following syntax:

```
2010-2013

:     State University of X, Y, Country.\newline Master's in X Sciences. Title: Title, Year of degree: 2013. Supervisor: Prof. Z
```

Edit these accordingly and you're good to go.

The last step is to make the pdf itself, it involves the use of a Makefile. In the same directory, run `make` and the pdf should be rendered and opened in the proper application. If you are using MacOS, you should edit the last line of the Makefile to read `open` instead of `xdg-open`, as I don't know whether Apple follows the free desktop standards.

### Acknowledgements

This cv is based on a custom version that I used up until recently, but now with strong influence from [Kieran Healy's](https://kieranhealy.org/vita.pdf) vita and from [Butterick's Practical Typography](http://practicaltypography.com/) pointers to a good typographical design.

[Source.](https://lf-araujo.github.io/posts/Yet-Another-CV)

Comment: While whitespace is important in a CV, this one seems to have too much whitespace. I would consider tightening the lists, e.g.

Comment: It can be easily achieved by changing the linespace command in the pandoc yaml.

Comment: I don't think so. Doesn't that just rely on `setspace`'s `\setstretch` command?  That is not what I meant.

Comment: Oh, I see, still relatively easy. Change the enumitem line to something like: `\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex}` and edit to your liking.

Comment: Nope, that does not work either. I am looking for a solution, the template have to be changed.

Comment: `\setlist{noitemsep}` or `\setlist{nosep}` for tight lists. But I was just suggesting you change the defaults so that there whitespace is diminished overall. (E.g., I'd also consider reducing the whitespace around section headings.) This was meant more as a suggestion for the defaults in general, not a question about how I might do it myself.  (I have my own CV design, which I'm quite happy with.)

Comment: Thanks. My aim is to make it more configurable, your input is relevant, that is why I am listening! I updated the code to allow changing the colors, the listings space and space below sections directly in the yaml. It will look a lot more condensed, it really improved the design.

Comment: Yeah, that does look better. And I think the idea of allowing the user to configure these sorts of settings in the yaml makes a lot of sense.